# unable to read and write xmal file on Databricks

Tags: python, xml, scala, apache-spark, databricks

```html
    <pre>
    %python
    spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net","XXXXXXXXXXXXX")



    df = spark.read \
     .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
     .option("rootTag", "catalog") \
     .option("rowTag", "book") \`enter code here`
     .load('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/sample.xml')
    </pre>
```

.load('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/sample.xml')

Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less

Comment: check that you have compatible version of the spark-xml library

Comment: Just one of many issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many thing wrong with the code snippet above.  I will show pointers on where to go and fix the issues.

First, I usually mount storage.  Please see the python [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts) to do this from books online at Microsoft.

Second, you are referring to /FileStore location.  This should be the path to the file placed in blob storage.

[image]

My file is called catalog.xml and was downloaded from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v=vs.85)).

Third, you should see the file if you run a listing command on your mount.

[image]

Alex is right about versions.  The maven library must match the cluster.  I had to down grade my DBR version to 9.1.  The image below shows the installed library.

[image]

The image below shows the Databricks Runtime.

[image]

What is most import is you do not need to reference the library in the format.  Just use "xml".

```
# file location
path = 'dbfs:/mnt/datalake/bronze/various/catalog.xml'

# read into df
df = spark.read \
    .format("xml") \
    .option("rootTag", "calalog") \
    .option("rowTag", "book") \
    .load(path)

# show data
display(df)

# show schema
df.printSchema
```

[image]

There are a lot more options that can be used with the read command.  Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/xml) for full details.